# How to run node.js as wget server?

Tags: node.js

Not very familiar with wget, but this is i'm trying to do.

There's a client code which does this:

wget http://serverIp:port/foldName/fileName

In the server side there's a lighttp server running, which i don't know much details.

Now i wrote a node.js server already, i want to let the client code call wget into this node.js to get files (to get rid of that lighttp server). What should i do in the node.js side to make this working ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try this example http://www.codexpedia.com/node-js/nodejs-http-file-server-serving-file-for-download/

Comment: Great, let me give it a try !